# Como separa palavra em letras no php?

Tags: php, string, explode

Quero separa uma string que não tem separação em uma array
exemplo

```
$s = "123";
$array=["1","2","3"];
```

tentei utilizar da seguinte maneira `valores = (array) explode("",$IdNota);` porém ele da ***Warning: explode(): Empty delimiter in /var/www/html/Model/model.php on line 572***

Alguém sabe o como que eu faço?

Comment: E precisa mesmo? O PHP já aceita indexação em string, tratando como array. Dependendo do caso já pode usar `$s[0]` ... etc sem precisar fazer nenhuma operação - Veja funcionando: https://ideone.com/hkmwt8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá. você pode usar uma função  `php`.

`str_split` **Converte uma string em um array.**

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-split.php

Ex:

```
$s = "123";
$valor = str_split($s);
print_r($valor);
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que a função `str_split` não é segura perante caracteres multi bytes

Comment: não entendo.  pode explicar oque seria caracteres multi bytes?

Comment: Caracteres unicode. Faça o teste para `str_split("pão")`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$string="123";
for( $i=0; $i < strlen($string) ; $i++ ){
   $array[$i]=$string[$i];
}
```

Vai imprimir algo assim:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `str_split` para converter uma string em um array.

Exemplo de Código:

```
<?php
$string = 123;
$split_length = 1;
$result = str_split ($string, $split_length);
?>
```

Resultado:

```
<?php
array (
 0 => '1',
 1 => '2',
 2 => '3',
);
?>
```

Você pode testar [nesse link](http://php.fnlist.com/string/str_split).

Comment: Vale lembrar que a função `str_split` não é segura perante caracteres multi bytes

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução mais simples é usando o `preg_split`, como abaixo:

```
$valores = preg_split('//u', $IdNota,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```